# SIOCGIFHWADDR for ioctlsocket in mingw

Tags: winapi, mingw, ioctl

I am using mingw to compile my cpp program which has to get MAC address. In unix, sys/ioctl.h
provides 'SIOCGIFHWADDR' to read it. But for mingw win32, there is a replacement for ioctl named as ioctlsocket. I am using it but it doesn't have 'SIOCGIFHWADDR' command.

How can I read the hardware MAC address using ioctlsocket?

Thanks in advance.

Following is the function I am using

```
ioctl(fd, SIOCGIFHWADDR, &ifr); //Unix it works
ioctlsocket(fd, SIOCGIFHWADDR, &ifr); //win32, doesn't work
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Answer (score 0):

There are a handful of different Windows APIs that will get the local MAC address for you.

[GetAdaptersAddresses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) should work for you.  (Look at the PhysicalAdddress member in the returned set of [IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366058%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

You can also use [GetIfTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366842%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and look at the bPhysAddr member in the returned set of MIB_IFROW structs.